# Vaadin: Adding placeholder to TextField

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to add placeholder to TextField similar to HTML5 placeholder property but I can't find the proper method for that. Is there any or the only way is to implement myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the `setInputPrompt` method.

API link: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractTextField.html#setInputPrompt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Note that in Vaadin 8, this is via the setPlaceholder() method.